# Problem trying to convert 2d touches to spritekit coordinates manually

Tags: swift, math, sprite-kit, game-engine, metal

I'm trying to convert 2d touches to sprite kit coordinates world space.
I know there's some convenience methods such as "convert(_:from:)".
but In my scenario i need to do it manually, I just don't know where to start.

Thank you

Comment: Can you illuminate us to your "scenario" that means you cannot use the built-in code?

Comment: Such an odd thing to request.  The built in function is going to do exactly what you need.  But if you absolutely need to do it manually,  , you need to figure out the percentage left and down you are from a particular view,  then translate it to the percentage left and down on where you would be on a scene.  So if you are 70% left, and 30% down on a view, you figure out where 70% left and 30% down is on the scene

Comment: I'm using SKRenderer with metal, such functions dont work if SKScene isnt in a skview

Comment: Ok well you need to figure out your percentages in the viewport then, and use that to determine where in the scene you are touching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         let width = screenSize.width
     let height:CGFloat = screenSize2.height

     //convert screen space to cartesian space
     let x = ((point.x * 720) / (width))  - (width)
     let y = ((-point.y * 1280) / (height))  + (height)
```

that worked, ratios